# how to filter many rows in R using dplyr and check element across datasets and keep same position

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, rbind

I have two datasets eqtl and gene-snp data:
They look like this:

```
dput(eqtl[1:4,1:6])
structure(list(Gene = c("ENSG00000132819", "ENSG00000101162", 
"ENSG00000132819", "ENSG00000101162"), `Gene-Chr` = c(20, 20, 
20, 20), `Gene-Pos` = c(55975426, 57598009, 55975426, 57598009
), RsId = c("rs6084653", "rs156356", "rs1741314", "rs6136489"
), `SNP-Chr` = c(20, 20, 20, 20), `SNP-Pos` = c(4157072, 1819280, 
4155193, 1923734)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

And:

```
dput(gene-snp[1:4,1:5])
structure(list(rf1 = c(55944944, 55944944, 55944944), rt1 = c(55984944, 
55984944, 55984944), rf2 = c(10219352, 10259352, 10299352), rt2 = c(10259352, 
10299352, 10339352), inf = c(0.968469914383, 2.251672668839, 
0.652762719771)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to see if the gene present in eqtl its position is present between rf1 and rt1:
if its present then select the rf1 and rt1 for which this position is present(there are many regions for similar rf1 and rt1)
Once the region is selected:
then look at the selected region: if SNP pos in eqtl data is present in between rf2 and rt2 position.

For example:
in eqtl there is gene which has position: 55975426
and its SNP has position:  4157072
Now search for this gene position in gene-snp file its this position is present between rf1 and rt1 then filter those region and look for SNP position from eqtl file for this gene in between rf2 and rt2

Similary do this for all the gene: and figure out for these genes: whether its snp can be found in the gene-snp file also or not. Calcuate the percentage:
I wrote this code: but the filter step doesn't give me all the rows that have rf1 and rt1 between the gene position:

```
    for(i in 1){ ##i will be gene in eqtl file
     for(j in 1910048:1910060){
       if((eqtl$`Gene-Pos`[i] %in% seq(gene-snp$rf1[j],gene-snp$rt1[j],1))==TRUE){
           value1 <- gene-snp$rf1[j]
           value2 <- gene-snp$rt1[j]
           regions <- gene-snp %>% filter(gene-snp$rt1==value1,gene-snp$rf2==value2))
}
}
```

After filtering: it generate only one region:
even though there are many rt1 and rf2 that belongs to value1 and value2.

[image]

Is there any way to solve this.
Thank you.